# LINQ JOIN ON TOP 1 ROW

Tags: sql, linq

I would like to do a LINQ join including only one row. In SQL, that's what I want to do :

`JOIN Person ON ( SELECT TOP (1) top1Person.ID FROM Person AS top1Person WHERE top1Person.CompanyID = Company.ID ) = Person.ID`

But I am not able to do it in LINQ, I tried this :

```
join pers in ctx.Persons on cmp.Persons.First().ID equals pers.ID
```

but the Fisrt() method is not allowed here...

Someone could help me ? Thanks

Comment: Showing all of your relevant code would help. Can you show your full SQL query and full LINQ query?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to accomplish that. One way would be to use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` on the result of query. Try this:

```
var results = (from id in ids
               join p in persons on id equals p.ID
               where p.CompanyID == companyID
               select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can do `OrderBy(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault()` first if you want the lowest ID first, or `OrderByDesc(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault()` if you want the highest first.

**EDIT**: Upon further inspection of your sample code, it looks like this may be more of what you're looking for.

```
var results = (from company in companies
               join p in persons on persons.First(x => x.CompanyID == company.ID).ID equals p.ID
               select p);
```

You should be able to call First() in that spot, but it looks like your LINQ query doesn't quite match up with your SQL. Should you be doing `ctx.Persons.First()` intstead of `cmp.Persons.First()`? If the above solution doesn't work for you, then we need more information.

**FINAL EDIT:** One last full solution for a slightly different interpretation. This code is tested and works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace com.test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> ids = new List<int>();
            List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

            persons.Add(new Person(1, 1, "John Smith"));
            persons.Add(new Person(2, 1, "Adam Jones"));
            persons.Add(new Person(3, 1, "Alex Rabbit"));
            persons.Add(new Person(4, 2, "Jessica Thurman"));
            persons.Add(new Person(5, 2, "Sam Riot"));
            persons.Add(new Person(6, 2, "Donald Lewis"));
            persons.Add(new Person(7, 3, "Lindsay Bonaparte"));
            persons.Add(new Person(8, 3, "Desmond Tutu"));
            persons.Add(new Person(9, 3, "Kevin Gargoyle"));
            persons.Add(new Person(10, 4, "Emily Francis"));
            persons.Add(new Person(11, 4, "Caitlin Elizabeth"));
            persons.Add(new Person(12, 4, "Harry Finstein"));
            persons.Add(new Person(13, 4, "Carla Loper"));

            companies.Add(new Company(1, "McDonalds", persons.Where(x => x.CompanyID == 1).ToList()));
            companies.Add(new Company(2, "Burger King", persons.Where(x => x.CompanyID == 2).ToList()));
            companies.Add(new Company(3, "Wendy's", persons.Where(x => x.CompanyID == 3).ToList()));
            companies.Add(new Company(4, "Arby's", persons.Where(x => x.CompanyID == 4).ToList()));

            var results = (from cmp in companies
                           join p in persons on cmp.Persons.First().ID equals p.ID
                           select p);

            foreach (var p in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Person: " + p.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int CompanyID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public Person (int id, int companyID, string name)
            {
                ID = id;
                CompanyID = companyID;
                Name = name;
            }
        }

        public class Company
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

            public Company(int id, string name, List<Person> persons)
            {
                ID = id;
                Name = name;
                Persons = persons;
            }
        }
    }
}
```